# [SOLVED] UDOO and rosserial-arduino: Unable to synch with device

Tags: ros, rosseral-arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm working to a robot project with ROS and UDOO. I'm using ROS Hydro and Ubuntu 13.04.

I followed the tutorial on the Wiki ROS but Hello World example is not working for me.

When I run:

```
rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py _port:=/dev/ttyUSB0
```

I can see following logs:

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1065.166800] ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [WallTime: 1065.213625] Connecting to /dev/ttymxc3 at 57600 baud
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1082.335425] Unable to synch with devices: possible link problem or link software version such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino
```

I followed the tutorial step by step (the only further step needed was to use

```
 chmod 777 /dev/ttymxc3 i
```

in order to have permission to access the serial port).

I installed ROS Hydro from scratch and Groovy was not installed before on my UDOO.

I also make a test with a dummy Arduino sketch to send a string over Serial and checking the result with:

```
cat /dev/ttymxc3
```

And I was able to see the messages on my console. So I'm sure communication works...

Any idea?

Thanks
Alessandro

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187845/%5Bsolved%5D-udoo-and-rosserial-arduino:-unable-to-synch-with-device.../) by [afranceson](https://answers.ros.org/users/19838/afranceson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 497 on 2014-07-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-26**:
You're obviously setting the serial port correctly. Perhaps the baud rate is wrong?

**Comment by [afranceson](https://answers.ros.org/users/19838/afranceson/) on 2014-07-27**:
I did not specify the baud rate in my sketch and, by default, it is 57600 (i also checked the arduino lib source code).

**Comment by [afranceson](https://answers.ros.org/users/19838/afranceson/) on 2014-07-27**:
One question: do the arduino send some message on serial port also if ros is not running on other side? I ask this because running cat /dev/ttymxc3 from terminal result in no output. If I should see something I can assume, at least, taht the problem is on arduino...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just on update for other users.

I found the problem on the roslib generated by rosserial_arduino. This bug was fixed on the sources for hydro on git but binary packages does not yet include it.

I install rosserial_arduino from source from git and it works fine.

Thanks
Ale

---

Originally posted by [afranceson](https://answers.ros.org/users/19838/afranceson/) with karma: 497 on 2014-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1